# How to show all filter values after filter one of them magento?

Tags: magento

I'm facing a problem. I want to show all attribute options after the filtering process done.

Suppose there are 3 filterable colors.

```
1 Red(5)
2 Blue(6)
3 Green(10)
```

Now Suppose i am clicking on Green(10) link from shop by block it will display all the products which contain Green colors. This is corrent but after getting the filtering results the other colors options didn't show again, but when I clear the filters it will show all Attribute options but this is not the way I want this to work.

Instead of this all color options should should still show even though a filter is active.

like once i click on Green(10) link after filtering process done i want to show all color options again!

same as before filtration process

like this

```
1 Red(5)
2 Blue(6)
3 Green(10)
```

How should I approach this problem?

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 things to be done here :

- Show the selected filter in layered navigation
- Show all the options for this filter

To show the selected filter in layered navigation we will need to rewrite `Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Attribute`.

To show every option of the selected filter we will have to rewrite `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Layer_Filter_Attribute` wich handles filters.

To do that, create a module and in etc/config.xml add rewrite directive for those models (in global section):

```
<models>
    <catalog>
        <rewrite>
            <layer_filter_attribute>Mycompany_Mymodule_Model_Layer_Filter_Attribute</layer_filter_attribute>
        </rewrite>
    </catalog>
    <catalog_resource>
        <rewrite>
            <layer_filter_attribute>Mycompany_Mymodule_Model_Resource_Layer_Filter_Attribute</layer_filter_attribute>
        </rewrite>
    </catalog_resource>
</models>
```

So then we create the model file `Attribute.php` in `Model/Layer/Filter`
We will simply rewrite the `apply` method :

```
class Mycompany_Mymodule_Model_Layer_Filter_Attribute extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Attribute
{
public function apply(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request, $filterBlock)
    {
        $filter = $request->getParam($this->_requestVar);
        if (is_array($filter)) {
            return $this;
        }
        $text = $this->_getOptionText($filter);

        if ($filter && strlen($text)) {
            $this->_getResource()->applyFilterToCollection($this, $filter);
            $this->getLayer()->getState()->addFilter($this->_createItem($text, $filter));
            // COMMENT OUT THIS LINE TO AVOID EMPTYING CURRENT ATTRIBUTE
            // $this->_items = array();
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Now create the model file `Attribute.php` in `Model/Resource/Layer/Filter`

This is where we will rewrite the `getCount` method to show every option for the filter.

Magento hides other options as there are no result for those. A shirt can't be red and white at the same time for a dropdown attribute. Thus count for red product is always 0 if white is selected.

So what we do here is trick Magento in making him believe that there are results for those options.

Here is the rewrite for `getCount` method :

```
class Mycompany_Mymodule_Model_Resource_Layer_Filter_Attribute extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Layer_Filter_Attribute
{
    public function getCount($filter)
        {
            // clone select from collection with filters
            // COMMENT OUT ORIGINAL LINE
            // $select = clone $filter->getLayer()->getProductCollection()->getSelect();
            // AND REWRITE USING SELECT FROM ORIGINAL CATEGORY COLLECTION INSTEAD OF FILTERED ONE
            $select = clone $filter->getLayer()->getCurrentCategory()->getProductCollection()->getSelect();
            // BELOW IS THE SAME AS ORIGINAL METHOD
            // reset columns, order and limitation conditions
            $select->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS);
            $select->reset(Zend_Db_Select::ORDER);
            $select->reset(Zend_Db_Select::LIMIT_COUNT);
            $select->reset(Zend_Db_Select::LIMIT_OFFSET);

            $connection = $this->_getReadAdapter();
            $attribute  = $filter->getAttributeModel();
            $tableAlias = sprintf('%s_idx', $attribute->getAttributeCode());
            $conditions = array(
                "{$tableAlias}.entity_id = e.entity_id",
                $connection->quoteInto("{$tableAlias}.attribute_id = ?", $attribute->getAttributeId()),
                $connection->quoteInto("{$tableAlias}.store_id = ?", $filter->getStoreId()),
            );

            $select
            ->join(
                array($tableAlias => $this->getMainTable()),
                join(' AND ', $conditions),
                array('value', 'count' => new Zend_Db_Expr("COUNT({$tableAlias}.entity_id)")))
                ->group("{$tableAlias}.value");

            return $connection->fetchPairs($select);
        }
    }
}
```

Basically what we did here is telling Magento to count from the original category product collection instead than the layered one. Thus counts are always the same ones as original category. (Of course they now dont make much sense if you mix them up with other attributes).

Et voilà! It should work as intended now.

Comment: this solution not working for me. i tried renaming these functions and still magento don't throw any error.